# Tips for skipping rain while in the wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I hate it when I'm far from everything, trying to climb something, and then... Rain.

I can't climb stuff, and making a fire to skip time is impossible because rain is wet.

If I don't want to teleport to a town to skip the time (some places can be quite remote from a town/shrine, and well I might not want to sit through 2 loading screens just for that), is there any trick that could help me skip rain?

Comment: find shelter and _then_ start a fire?

Comment: Yeah I guess but was hoping for something more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the best way to skip rain is to attempt to [make a fire under an overhang or find one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5yu5az/how_do_i_stopskip_rainthunder/):

> Best thing you can do is make a campfire under an overhang, or find one already active, and sit beside it.

A lot of forums, such as [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75107313) recommend the upgraded [climbing gear](http://www.gosunoob.com/zelda-breath-of-wild/climbing-armor-set-location/) if you want to try and climb in the rain. You can apparently *jump, slide down some, jump, slide down some, repeat* to still progress while its raining.

> The trick is to climb a bit and then jump, you will slide down to where you were before jumping. The climbing set will help with this since you'll lose less stamina upon jumping. But nothing I found so far stops you from sliding down a bit.

The linked Reddit above also states the same thing:

> If you get the full Climbing gear set, and upgrade it to the point of having the set bonus, "rain climbing" aka climbing 5 steps up, jumping, sliding down, climbing 5 up, jumping, sliding down, rinse, lather, repeat, will get you progress, and you can still get up a fairly large number of cliffs that way if you have already upgraded your Stamina wheel a fair bit.

Comment: The 5-step-jump in the rain does work quite well, that's what I end up doing for smaller walls.

Comment: It helps to have the power from beating the flying divine beast over the Rito Village as a head start as well as Timmy Jim's suggestion.  Rain is annoying when you're trying to cross a mountain, but the climbing gear plus Rivali's Gale work well enough for most cases.